# Better syntax highlighting for Javascript in Notepad++

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ in writing Javascript files. But the syntax highlighting is not that good there.

For example methods and properties of known objects, like arrays, numbers or even AJAX object are not highlighted at all.

Can this be improved by adding a plugin or something ? if so can you specify a plugin for me ?

Thanks

Comment: No clue why anyone is voting to move this to Super User. In any case, the syntax highlighting isn't all that great for other languages with built-in members and methods for built-in types either.

Comment: Notepad++ has a very powerful built-in configuration that allows you to 9also) specify the colors for all the things you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++ you can go to the plugins tab and then to plugin manager and it will show you all available and installed plugins. Just scroll down the list until you find one that suits your needs and install it. If you don't see it on the list I don't think you will find it anywhere else.